# MySQL - mysql date format suffix (1st, 2nd, 3rd...)

Tags: php, mysql

I doubt there is, but I was just wondering if I can apply a suffix directly to a date number in my MySQL query, rather than have to attack it again with PHP? In other words, I am currently querying

```
DATE_FORMAT(Date,"%d %b %y")
```

Which gives me **13** Jul 12. Can I get a query that would serve up **13th** Jul 12?

If not, what is the most efficient way of applying a suffix? At the moment, I am exploding the string into an array, running the day variable through a function to apply the correct suffix, then concatenating all the variables together again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
DATE_FORMAT(Date,"%D %b %y")
```

From the MySQL manual for DATE_FORMAT:

%D  Day of the month with English suffix (0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, …)